# How to change the format in the DataTable's Google Chart API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

- I would like to change the format of the data in the DataTable in
  order to make it more flexible and the Chart is still the same with
  the first one.

**Default:**

```
['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
['2004',  1000,      400],
['2005',  1170,      460],
['2006',  660,       1120],
['2007',  1030,      540]
```

**It must be:**

```
['Year', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007'],
['Sales', 1000, 1170, 660, 1030],
['Expenses', 400 ,460, 1120, 540]
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/XWaLK/)</kbd>**

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must transpose array like: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/Mw398/1/

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(transposeArray([
    ['Year', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007'],
    ['Sales', 1000, 1170, 660, 1030],
    ['Expenses', 400, 460, 1120, 540]
]));

function transposeArray(array) {
  return array[0].map(function (col, i) {
    return array.map(function (row) {
      return row[i];
    });
  });
}
```

Before pass data to `arrayToDataTable` you mast prepare it in format that google charts will understand.

Transpose – http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Method `map` – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now :-)