# Javascript, restructuring array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to draw a google chart and I have a data from Api in array format. I am trying to restructure it to the format that google chart accepts.. I have been trying to manage but with no luck... its a problem of structuring loops in right way but i am stuck

```
{
      "rows": [
        [
          "20140803",
          "29917",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "20140803",
          "30022",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "20140804",
          "29917",
          "1"
        ],
        [
          "20140805",
          "29917",
          "3"
        ],
        [
          "20140805",
          "30022",
          "3"
        ],
        [
          "20140807",
          "29917",
          "6"
        ],
        [
          "20140807",
          "30022",
          "2"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

This is an array I receive.. here first value in each row is date, second is article id, third is number of views...
to create a graph i need array in the format of (just a example)

```
[date,     article_id1, article_id2, article_id3, article_id2,......]
[20140731,     12,         222,        0,       0]
[20140732,     333,         0,         0,       12]
```

Here the number of article id api gives in not fixed, also if I don't have data for that date to that article I would have to put 0..

More in brief.. Google Chart requires data in format such as

```
['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
['2004',  1000,      400],
['2005',  1170,      460],
['2006',  660,       1120],
['2007',  1030,      540]
```

So I am plotting graph with respect to each article id (like sale, expenses in example)

If any one could give me any heads up that would be really very helpful.. Thanks

Comment: You receive JSON I assume, why are you posting here php's print_r. It would be easier to help you, if you gave real structure to play with.

Comment: You want to restructure it in `PHP` or `JS`? Since you have shown `PHP` code, you have control over JSON you create, why don't you create the structure correctly first time itself?

Comment: Yes this is a Var_dump output.. I am sending it to javascript.. since the output is very large in json so I though i will be presentable and understandable in this format.

Comment: @Салман: Its the response from API which I can't control.

Comment: @dfsq: I have edited the description and added json file. Hope that would be easy for you to help me.. thanks

Comment: your post is confusing. from reading it I can not tell if you want to restructure the array in php or js. It is also hard to tell what structure you have now and what structure you need. If you explain these things better it should be easy for someone to help you.

Comment: @user98239820 I still don't understand the format you want. Is it `[date, id1, id2, ...]` or `[date, views1, views2, ...] (with sorted id or no?)`

Comment: You still don't state if you want to do it in PHP or Javascript

Comment: @parchment: i want 
header = [date, id1, id2,, id3]
value = [2012-12-12, view1, view2, view3] 
the format that google chart requires is <b>
 ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
 ['2004',  1000,      400],
 ['2005',  1170,      460],
 ['2006',  660,       1120],
 ['2007',  1030,      540]

Comment: @2pha: I want to do it in javascript

Comment: @user98239820 you want, you want ... why don't you tried ?

Comment: @martialdidit: I couldn't so I am asking for help.. Thanks

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281369/how-to-change-the-format-in-the-datatables-google-chart-api-with-javascript

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski don't think so, it's more complex than a simple transpose.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski: Thanks for the link but it is complex then that..

Answer (score 1):

Here is one I came up with. Everything is done in the covert function. The rest is just for show.
http://jsfiddle.net/oxpasrnh/

It is probably not the best though, someone should be able to improve on it.

```
I don't want to post code, just look at the fiddle
```

Comment: Thanks @2pha so much for your effort.. thanks alot.. I think this will give me good direction to move ahead.